# Are there any fallbacks for Plymouth?

Tags: plymouth

If I am using the proprietary driver, I don't get a good boot screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a workaround to make plymouth use framebuffer: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml

Comment: I wouldn't trust softpedia from my experience.

Comment: @garbagecollection: Than write some better information. There is enough space here or at the Ubuntu community help wiki (http://help.ubuntu.com/community)

Answer (score 4):

- First open the software center

[image]

- Install v86d

[image]

- Now Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gksu gedit`

[image]

- Now click on 'Open' and  Press the pencil button .

[image]

- Now paste `/etc/default/grub`
- Now Replace the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` (Line no 11 according to gedit) with

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset       video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-32,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap` (you can replace 1290x1024 with your own resolution .

-Also replace `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` (Line 25 according to gedit ) with GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024

-Now your grub file looks like this

[image]

- Save the file .
- Now click open again and paste `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` in the location .
- Paste `uvesafb mode_option=1280x1024-32 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap` at the end of the file (again you can replace 1280x1024 with your own resolution) .

[image]

- Now create a new file and paste `FRAMEBUFFER=y` and then save the file with the name splash to `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d` .
- Now Open the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and paste this.

  `sudo update-grub2 && sudo update-initramfs -u`
- You are done!!

[Source](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your definition of "good".

There is a fallback: usplash and/or xsplash. These should load automatically. They do here on systems where Plymouth doesn't work.

Plymouth requires KMS which is only available on open source drivers (AFAIK). This means if you're running the closed ATI/Nvidia drivers, you'll have an ugly boot experience.

I personally just turn off quiet and splash from the kernel arguments and watch a load of text scroll up the screen. It's only there for a few seconds, lets me know what's going on and it doesn't waste time loading up images.